# Making SMS verification codes easily copyable

Tags: sms, twilio, sms-verification

I am sending users a 10 digit numbers and letters code through text as a method of 2FA. My use case is a bit different -- not your typical login 2FA code, but rather a passcode that can be used to unlock an encrypted document. This is why my codes need to be longer than just a few digits.

I'm looking for it to be easily copyable by users -- sometimes iPhone makes it so you can click a code in text and easily copy it. This appears on 6-digit numeric, but doesn't appear to be working for anything above 9 digits as far as I can tell.

Is there a set pattern that can tell iPhone that the code being sent is a verification code? Like a digit threshold or a format?

My current message looks something like this:

```
Thank you for signing up for XYZ. Your verification code is: JWtCtWJmD2g
```

I am also thinking about just sending just the code (with no description) or sending two messages -- an introduction and then the code on separate lines.

Comment: This isn't the answer to your question (apologies in advance), but I'd really recommend you check out Authy over building custom 2FA: https://www.twilio.com/docs/authy. You may run into SMS deliverability issues because 2FA messages look a lot like spam from the perspective of mobile carriers. Authy solves this by using pre-registered short codes and international numbers to make delivery of 2FA easy.

Comment: Additionally SIM swapping is becoming more prevalent, making SMS-based 2FA less secure. Authy allows you to integrate soft-tokens and push authentications into your app so that you're relatively more future-proof.

Comment: @CharlieWeems -- Thanks for the link. I added some more details about my use case in the question, it (may be) a bit unique which is why I'm not just copying the standard SMS 2FA template that I've seen most companies use. I do think a short code could be useful, but my volume isn't high enough to warrant switching.

Comment: I can't speak to your use-case in particular, but typically it's best to treat anything sent via SMS as insecure (SMS is not encrypted). Because you can't trust that your code won't be delivered without being viewed by a man-in-the-middle, the security value of 2FA is that it can be used to verify you're in possession of the device within a short window of time (e.g. 10 minute validity period). You will typically also specify a max number of attempts to prevent brute-forcing of the code. I'd personally recommend against using an SMS code like a password due to lack of encryption in transit.

Comment: I did a quick look through the iMessage developer docs as well and as far as I can tell Apple doesn't offer a way to change this behavior. I also wasn't able to find clear documentation on what will be recognized as a 2FA code unfortunately.

Comment: @CharlieWeems I can't find it, but I just saw an article the other day about a proposal for a universal format for SMS 2FA code texts, mainly to make them more machine readable. I believe a key component was always following ```Your {{company}} code is {{code}}. #{{company}} #{[code}}.``` The pound signs making it very easy for apps to pick up.

Comment: @CharlieWeems See my posted answer

Answer (score 2):

As of February 2020, there appears to be no standardized format for SMS 2FA codes. There is currently a [proposal](https://github.com/WebKit/explainers/tree/master/sms-one-time-code-format) from an engineer at Apple to create a unified format for SMS delivery.

I have found that iPhone is good at picking up "Here is your code: _____" regardless of how many digits / alphanumeric as long as:

- 10 or fewer characters
- Not a real word
- No special characters (@, &)
- The code is on the same line as "here is your code:"
- There is at least 1 digit and it is not on the end of the string surrounded by letters ("7AsPlQd" and "xAsPlQd12" do not work)

---

Update: Oct 2020: I can now auto copy with 10 or fewer (was 9 or fewer before)

Answer (score 1):

The standard mentioned above was announced by Apple on August 4th. You can now specify a custom code and domain using the following format:

```
747723 is your ExampleCo authentication code.
    
@example.com #747723
```

The first line is freeform text. The second line specifies the domain for which the code is valid and then provides the code after the `#`.

You can also add `autocomplete=one-time-code` to the form field that is expecting the 2FA code.